# How to prevent new line with TypeWriter effect in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text, alignment

The TypeWriter effect seems to insert a new line when I implement it, but I would really prefer it to read out on the same line.
Please see attached

[image]

Please advise on how I can get this in the same line? Thanks

```
<h3>
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';
....

               I'm a {city} based <Typewriter options={{ strings: ['Software Engineer'],autoStart: true,loop: true,}}/>  
               {description}
            </h3>
```

Comment: What CSS are you using

Answer (score 0):

You could add a css rule with `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline`;